# How to add a ValidationMessage for a specific item in a List property using Blazor EditForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Using the EditForm component in Blazor Server.

I want to validate all child items in a List<> property and show a validation message next to the input.
The validation is triggered, and the validation messages appear in the summary, but not next to the individual inputs.

I use IValidatableObject on the parent model to loop all items in the list and create a ValidationResult, but I have no idea what I should fill in as 'membername' parameter in the ValidationResult constructor.

**ParentModel class:**

```
public class ParentItemModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public List<ChildItemModel> ChildItems { get; set; } = new List<ChildItemModel>();

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        int i = 0;

        if (ChildItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ChildItems)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Data))
                {
                    var result = new ValidationResult($"Required field", new[] { $"ChildItems[{i}].Data" });
                    results.Add(result);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

**ChildModel class:**

```
public class ChildItemModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; } = "";
}
```

**Editform in razor component:**

```
<EditForm Model="@ParentItem" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">

        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div>
            @foreach (var child in ParentItem.ChildItems)
            {
                <div>
                    <input type="text" @bind="child.Data" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => child.Data)" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blazor, `DataAnnotationsValidator` doesn't support nested models.

You're using what I think is older MVC validation which only logs messages into the message store.  In order to identify messages with fields/properties you need to do things a little differently.

I would suggest using something like Fluent Validation, but creating your own for specific instances isn't difficult.  Here's how to do something simple with your code.

Your model:

```cs
public class ParentItemModel
{
    public List<ChildItemModel> ChildItems { get; set; } = new List<ChildItemModel>();

    public void Validate(ValidationMessageStore? validationStore)
    {
        if (validationStore is null)
            return;

        // clear our section of the message store
        validationStore.Clear();

        foreach (var item in ChildItems ?? new())
        {
            // add any new messages using a FieldIdentifier instance to specify the object instance and the property name 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Data))
                validationStore.Add(new FieldIdentifier(item, nameof(item.Data)), $"{nameof(item.Data)} is a Required field");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the edit page.  I've added comments throughout to explain what's happening.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnValidSubmit=HandleValidSubmit>
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div>
        @foreach (var child in ParentItem.ChildItems)
        {
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind="child.Data" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => child.Data)" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private ParentItemModel ParentItem = new() { ChildItems = new List<ChildItemModel> { new ChildItemModel { Data = "me" }, new ChildItemModel { Data = string.Empty } } };

    private EditContext editContext = default!;
    private ValidationMessageStore? _validationMessageStore;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Set up the edit context
        editContext = new EditContext(ParentItem);
        // create our message store. What we get is our own private section of the store which we can edit.  We can't update other processes sections.  We must use the same store instance throughout in order to clear out old messages
        _validationMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
        // wire up an event handler to trigger validation events emitted by the Edit Context
        editContext.OnValidationRequested += this.OnValidationRequested;
    }

    // Validation Evenbt Handler
    private void OnValidationRequested(object? sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        // call the validation routine on the model
        ParentItem.Validate(_validationMessageStore);
        // Tell the edit context that validation state may have changed 
        // it will raise the OnValidationAtateChanged event so the Validation Summary and Messages can update
        editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    // A valid submit occurs when the ValidationMessageStore is empty
    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // do your stuff
    }

    // Dispose the event handler correctly
    public void Dispose()
        => editContext.OnValidationRequested -= this.OnValidationRequested;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was indeed on a wrong path using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations which does not work for Blazor.

Comment: I added _validationMessageStore.Clear() in OnValidationRequested so validation messages are reset on every submit.